# cordova alljoyn peer to peer chat not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, alljoyn

I'm working on an   ionic android application with Alljoyn framework for peer to peer message transfers and got a sample project from  https://github.com/AllJoyn-Cordova/cordova-chat-alljoyn  but when I run the same app on 2 device,channel created by one device is not shown in second  device even though both device are in same network.some one please help ??..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both the devices are connected to the same Wi-Fi Access point and that access point supports multi-cast.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but   both devices are connected  under same wifi  network(supports multicast) still  not working.In that sample, i just created  a channel in one device and tried to send chat  message from it but nothing shown in 2nd device.